# Convert jquery function to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this function but I can't seem to translate a few of the lines successfully.

```
$('.text').each(function() {
  str = String($(this).html()); #this line
  tot = str.length;
  str = (tot <= max) ? str : str.substring(0,(max + 1))+"..."; #this line
  $(this).html(str); #this line
});
```

How can I convert this into a javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text').forEach(function(el){
var str = el.innerHTML;
var tot = str.length;
...
this.innerHTML = str;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text').forEach(el => {
   str = el.innerHTML;
   tot = str.length;
   str = (tot <= max) ? str : str.substring(0,(max + 1))+"..."; 
   el.innerHTML = str;
})
```

Comment: Don't use `getElementsByClassName` unless you explicitly want an `HTMLCollection` instead of a `NodeList`.